# How do I read input ID dynamically and place its value in text jQUery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to read the value of the `input` and updating it in `P` tag, value would be dynamic.

**UPDATE:** on each update click, value should replace below in the paragraph

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="Q_Star1_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value One"> - <a id="test1" href="javascript:;">Update</a>
<input id="Q_Star2_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Two"> - <a id="test2" href="javascript:;">Update</a>
<input id="Q_Star3_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Three"> - <a id="test3" href="javascript:;">Update</a>
<input id="Q_Star4_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Four">- <a id="test4" href="javascript:;">Update</a>
<input id="Q_Star5_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Five"> - <a id="test5" href="javascript:;">Update</a>

<p class="final-text">Replace This</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $("#test").on('click', function() {
    var inputVal = $("#Q_Star1_Text").val();
    $(".final-text").text(inputVal);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code working fine. what you want now? on each click of link get next input data and update it? that's what you want?

Comment: @31piy Actually I wasnt able make it more clear..actually next to each input there is a button to for update..and on each button click, the parapgraph will update..for Example if I click on Value Three then value three will get updated to the paragraph.I will update my question as well

Comment: @SanjeevKumar -- your code snippet is incomplete, leading to a number of incorrect answers. Please make sure you post a complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar  please edit your question and add correct HTML so that we can change our answer accordingly to make it valuable for you

Comment: @31piy question updated

Comment: @SanjeevKumar  check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `click` event of the `a` tags and on click, fetch the value of the previous `input` using `prev()`:

```js
$("a[id^=test]").on('click', function() {
  var value = $(this).prev('input[id^=Q_Star]').val();
  $('.final-text').text(value);
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="Q_Star1_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value One"> - <a id="test1" href="javascript:;">Update</a>
<input id="Q_Star2_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Two"> - <a id="test2" href="javascript:;">Update</a>
<input id="Q_Star3_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Three"> - <a id="test3" href="javascript:;">Update</a>
<input id="Q_Star4_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Four">- <a id="test4" href="javascript:;">Update</a>
<input id="Q_Star5_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Five"> - <a id="test5" href="javascript:;">Update</a>

<p class="final-text">Replace This</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an working example**

```js
$(".test111").on('click', function() {
  $("[name='starValue']").each(function() {
    var element = $("." + this.id);
    if (element.length) {
      element.html(this.value);
    } else {
      $("<p class='" + this.id + "'>" + this.value + "</p>").appendTo(".content");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
<input id="Q_Star1_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value One">
<input id="Q_Star2_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Two">
<input id="Q_Star3_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Three">
<input id="Q_Star4_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Four">
<input id="Q_Star5_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Five">
<a class="test111" href="javascript:;">Update Text</a>
<p class="Q_Star1_Text">Replace This</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: read your updated description. Here is a working solution.

Updated html:

```
<input id="Q_Star1_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value One">
  <p class="replace">Replace This</p>
<input id="Q_Star2_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Two">
  <p class="replace">Replace This</p>
<input id="Q_Star3_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Three">
  <p class="replace">Replace This</p>
<input id="Q_Star4_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Four">
  <p class="replace">Replace This</p>
<input id="Q_Star5_Text" type="text" name="starValue" value="Value Five">
  <p class="replace">Replace This</p>
<a class="test111" href="javascript:;">Update Text</a>
```

Working js, simple and effective:

```
  $(".replace").on('click', function() {
    var prevElem = $(this).prev().val();
    $(this).text(prevElem)
  });
```